# java, concurrency, executors

Tags: java, concurrency

I have simple class that uses ExecutorService and calculate PI using Monte Carlo method.

```
  public class MonteCarlo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    long numberOfWorkers = 1000000;
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double radius = 5.0;
    long numberOfAllShoots = 0;

    Set<Future<Integer>> futures = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfWorkers;i++) {
        long shootNumber = 500;
        numberOfAllShoots+=shootNumber;
        Callable callable = new Shoot(x,y,radius,shootNumber);
        Future<Integer> future = executorService.submit(callable);
        futures.add(future);
    }

    int numberOfCorrectShoots = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
        numberOfCorrectShoots += future.get();
    }
    executorService.shutdown();

    double pi = 4 * ((double)numberOfCorrectShoots / numberOfAllShoots );

    System.out.printf("PI is approximated to " + pi);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("\n"+(end - start) + " miliseconds ");

}
```

}

but the problem is that I get almost the same running time when I set newFixedThreadPool argument high like 100 or 2. The result is the same using newSingleThreadExecutor .
What is wrong with this code ? I expected that using newFixedThreadPool will be much faster than single thread

EDIT

Shoot class

```
   public class Shoot implements Callable {

private final double x;
private final double y;
private final double radius;
private final long numberOfShoots;

public Shoot(double x, double y, double radius, long numberOfShoots) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.numberOfShoots = numberOfShoots;
}

@Override
public Integer call() {
    int numberOfCorrectShoot = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfShoots;i++) {
        double t = randomDoubleFromRange(x-radius,x+radius);
        double u = randomDoubleFromRange(y-radius,y+radius);
        if((x-t)*(x-t) + (y-u)*(y-u) <= radius * radius) {
            numberOfCorrectShoot++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfCorrectShoot;
}

private double randomDoubleFromRange(double rangeMin, double rangeMax) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * random.nextDouble();
}
```

}

nproc command return 2

I tried numberOfWorkers = 400 and shootNumber = 1000000 and both newSingleThreadExecutor and newSingleThreadExecutor(2) or more give result about 51000 ms

Comment: Possibly the time is expended in synchronization overhead?  Try 400 workers and 10000000 shoots per worker.  Also, there might be something about your Shoot class.

Comment: There is often a lot of overhead with Thread creation. Also, check how many cores you have available. Since java threads are user threads, they could all be on the same core.

Comment: Thread creation is expensive. Take the start time after you have created Thread Pool and see if that reduces the processing time.

Comment: what is the spec of the machine on which you are running this code?